# Laravel Image Upload Validation Fails

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, upload, image-uploading

When I try to upload an image within Laravel the validation is not working. Here my validation string...

```
'cover' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048'
```

The validation error I get is `The cover must be an image`. It does work however when I only have the required rule.

What is the problem?

Comment: What does your `<form>` element look like? Are you using `enctype="multipart/form-data"`?

Comment: please update your question to include the html

Answer (score 1):

**You can remove the rule `'image'` on your validation :**

```
'cover' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
```

Hope it help u :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
'cover' => 'required|image|max:2048',
```